# K&R C book pointer part

Tags: c, pointers

Some confusion about C language pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = 1, y = 2, z[10];
    int *ip;/* ip is a pointer which points to int  */
    ip = &x;
    printf("%p\n", ip);
    return 0;
}
```

In my machine, when I compile use cc, and run it:
it will give me some output like this:
0x7ffeae379990
The hexadecimal value is 96-bit in binary format, but my machine is 64-bit

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

So I expect some value which is 64-bit long, but this one is not, I'm a little confused about that, could anyone help me a bit??

Comment: Why do you think 0x7ffeae379990 is a 96-bit number?

Comment: my terrible math, I realize that it is 12 * 4 = 48-bit, but it's not 64-bit value either

Comment: Sure it is, you just have leading 0s.  0x00007ffeae379990

Comment: the pointer is a pointer to memory, and there is no guarantee that the architecture of your system (32-bit vs 64-bit) is the same as the memory page size of your OS

Comment: @Stephen Newell, well, great answer, I missed out the leading 4 zero, It does NOT print out... So it is indeed 64-bit, as our machine is 64-bit, thx!

Comment: @Thomas side-note: currently, most 64b architectures don't actually use a 64b address space. IIRC AMD64 currently only supports 48b virtual addresses, so you should never get pointers larger than 48 bits effective. IIRC ARMv8.0 defined a 49b virtual address space and ARMv8.2 *optionally* supports 52b (LVA feature).

Comment: Incidentally this allows smuggling data in the upper end of pointers, for instance since 2013 ObjC [can smuggle instance refcounts in the class pointer](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html).

Comment: @Masklinn, thx for your deeper explanation, actually the address is what it actually is, not hiding the leading 0s,it is 48-bit long value, I totally understand it now!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a "96-bit binary format" . It's a binary number, represented with hexadecimal notation, whose value is the in-memory address of the x variable ( different from the value that the x variable actually holds, in this case 1) .In this scenario the machine being 32bit or 64bit should not interfere with the concept the book try to show you.